# How to prevent word breaking?

Tags: memoir

Is there a way to prevent the whole document to use word breaking?

I have seen some options such as `\raggedright{}` but that is not elegant for a book.

Comment: Much less elegant is not having hyphenation, IMHO.

Comment: If you don't mind the result looking like the output from Word ... The results cannot look good if you use no hyphenation with justified text unless you use either a tiny font or very large pages. (Even then, hyphenation would give a superior result, in all probability.)

Comment: You could write a book using only words which TeX will not hyphenate, I suppose. That should include plenty of short words, so the line breaking algorithm should be able to cope. Of course, this might restrict the content of the book slightly, but perhaps it would be the optimal solution, all things considered.

Comment: Also consider using microtype to reduce the number of hyphenations (also this question is not related to the memoir class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` in your document according 
to [Stopping all hyphenation](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-hyphoff.html). But in the overall, it might not be a perfect idea.